# Adding custom parameter to ADF ARM template

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have an ADF pipeline. The task is to productionize the pipeline. I am using azure devops CI/CD (classic). I am following this documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery-resource-manager-custom-parameters

I have to move the pipeline to test and prod. Thereforem, there are many parameters that are parametrized but few parameters like sql user_name, secret_name are not parametrized.

I want to edit the ARM template and add custom parameter so that I do not have to edit the template.json and paramete-template.json and push them again to repo. The edit option in adf allows to create custom params and therefore generate these in ARM templates when exported.

[image]

I have the parameter in the template.

[image]

The parameter secretName doesnt appear in ARM template in CD flow
[image]

Answer (score 1):

After lot of tries and understanding the credential structure the ADF follows for different LinkedServices, we have found that to parametrize a custom nested argument, we have to specify the argument in a nested form. The parameter configuration needs to be edited like this:

[image]

For example, the secret name for SQL linked service (using password – connected to azurekeyvault) needs to be like this:

```
"password": {
    "secretName": "="
 }
```

But for the secret type (from azure keyvault) for storage linked service, it has to be like this:

```
"servicePrincipalCredential": {
    "secretName": "="
}
```

And then these args can be passed directly from azure keyvault if variable groups are connected to keyvault. This solves the problem we were facing.

Answer (score 0):

Which mode you are using to configure the parameters?

> **ARM parameter configuration is only enabled in "GIT mode". Currently it is disabled in "live mode" or "Data Factory" mode.**

So, as per above official statement from Microsoft, you should be using Git repository.

Also, take note - Creating a custom Resource Manager parameter configuration creates a file named `arm-template-parameters-definition.json` in the root folder of your git branch. **You must use that exact file name.**

There are other multiple ways which you can try to pass secrets in ARM template. Refer this article from [devkimchi.com](https://devkimchi.com/2019/04/24/6-ways-passing-secrets-to-arm-templates/).

Comment: Hi,Thanks for answering. Yes, I am using Git mode and using correct file.